# Multiple select field in LocomotiveCMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms

I need to set up a field in LocomotiveCMS that is similar to Select but allows multiple selections. Something like  in HTML... does LocomotiveCMS allow for that, or will I have to do some ruby coding to get that to work?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I need this too! A listbox (select with "multiple" attribute) or a series of checkboxes would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still a thing.

I'm unsure whether your question relates to fields within the Locomotive CMS Back Office or on the front end so I've addressed both below.

### Front End

Irrespective of whether or not you're dealing with Locomotive CMS content types, either of the following will allow selection of multiple values on the front end:

- Listbox (`select` element with the [multiple attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select))
- A series of checkbox inputs with the same value in the `name` property

### Back Office

If you need to allow selection of multiple values within the Back Office, you can do this for content types using the `has_many` or `many_to_many` [content type relationships](https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/relate-two-content-types).

If you need multiple value selection outside of content types (e.g. in metafields schema) you're unfortunately out of luck.